# how to force MVC 4 bundle to render links with full domain address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

Is it possible to force ASP.NET MVC 4 bundle to render links with full domain address?
I mean a bundle like this: `~/bundle/jquery` render to `http://domain.com/bundle/jquery` instead of this one: `/bundle/jquery`.

**UPDATE:**

I think I should explain more. By *`render`* I mean the rendered url, not the page. e.g. I have a bundle with this key: `~/bundle/jquery`. OK. It will be rendered as

```
<script src="/bundle/jquery" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Right? Well, I want this one instead:

```
<script src="http://sub.domain.com/bundle/jquery" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I dont thinks so, what I always do is add a baseurl in the webconfig for this kind of things

Answer (score -1):

Do you exactly say it "render"?? yes, then ASP.NET MVC 4 renders them as you have asked for.You can notice this by going to the source code of the page RENDERED by a view in ASP.NET MVC 4.0.

You don't have to force it as such , it automatically does it for you...!!

**EDITED:**
You can do so by deleting `Bundle.cs` file in the `App_Start folder` and removing the  `BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);` line from `Global Application Class`. But you will have to add paths to your required files manually. this is cumbersome. Moreover, this will reduce your application's performance as you will be adding the plain HTML on View Page.

Comment: @king.net:..Rendering is done at the server-side by the view by putting all the Configured Bundles and Configured Paths as a whole and after there intrpretation HTML is RENDERED which has the same paths those you have asked in your question...you can notice them by going into the source code through any browser